# screencapture using java applet

Tags: java

Trying to figure out how can I create a screencapture applet like screenr.com does .. i want to be able to produce a similar result.

I found that there are ways to capture screenshot.. from a signed applet.. but can't seem to find any information on video capture.

thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use java.awt.Robot to take screenshot .... This is simple Java code snippet .. you can break the video in individual frames and then use the capture code...

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FilePrinter 
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("c:/temp/test.png"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Someone call a doctor!");
    }

}
}
```

Hope this will be useful ...

**Update:**
Refer to the following link for getting individual frames. The guy is using 'Java Media Framework' to do that ...

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=421678&start=0

**UPDATE**

---

1. http://java.dzone.com/tips/screen-record-play-using-java
2. http://javagraphics.blogspot.com/2008/06/movies-writing-mov-files-without.html

The first one uses JMF for converting jpeg into video and the other one is a branch of apples real time movie codec (which is deprecated now).

Let me know if it works or if you have come with something new :)

Regards and happy new year.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I can capture the screenshots but how do I capture it as a video? The link talks about how to get picture frames from a video.. i am kinda looking for the other way around.

Comment: @Jhon Stewart: Sorry I was kind of stuck in other things. Hope you would have a solution for this by now. :). I have updated my answer with two links for using java.awt.Robot and converting it into a movie. :)

Answer (score 1):

jCapture is a Java applet which allows to capture screen shots or record screen activity and audio and upload them directly to your web application (wiki, CMS, etc.) With jCapture you can quickly create documentation pages for UI-rich software products.

It is built-in to Tiki 10 and is available via a plug-in for DokuWiki, saving directly to the media manager.

It will be ported other web applications.

Key features
* Select screen area
* Capture screenshot as PNG, JPG, etc.
* Record video
** Audio from microphone
** Pause during the recording
** Play before upload
** Post-recording editor to remove frames
** Pick splash frame
** Generates a .swf file

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcapture-applet/